# Dissertation: correct writing of a numbered list

Tags: british-english, lists, academia, academic-writing

Are there any grammatical rules for numbered lists (my university does not have a guideline for this)?

Which format would be correct for the given example of numbered objectives? Two things that I prefer: I would like to use numbered list with points (not brackets) and I would like to use an introductory/leading sentence above.

The first sentence should end with a "dash"? Each of the objectives ends with a full stop?

> Specific objectives of the study are listed as below **-**
>
> **1.**    To assess ... **.**
>
> **2.**    To evaluate ... **.**
>
> **3.**    To examine ... **.**

Comment: With a colon? "**1.** To assess the xxx:" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For doctoral dissertations, the University itself would be seriously lacking for want if it didn't have in its library a resource for Ph.d students to answer this question. My advice to you is to start there.

Example: Harvard University has theirs online "Formatting Your Dissertation" with many keypoints and tips. https://gsas.harvard.edu/degree-requirements/dissertations/formatting-your-dissertation

Oxford University has their entire library database of theses and dissertations depending on field of study online. (Search "Theses and Dissertations").

Avoid straying off the path too far.

Comment: Thanks! Google search finally gave one useful answer about this: https://www.purchase.edu/editorial-style-guide/general-style-preferences/punctuation/bulleted-and-numbered-lists/